# How to replace specific cells in a Pandas dataframe based on a common primary key with another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I'm trying to code in Python after a hiatus of 4 years and facing difficulties in implementing my ideas. I have 2 large excel sheets consisting of more than 12k x 70 values, both have the same number of columns and column names. I've created a primary key for both the dataframes and now I want to compare values from the primary key of one sheet to primary key of another and when there's a match I want to replace certain values(not all) from the old sheet to the new.
eg
df1:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   2   3   4   5   6
7   8   9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18
```

df2:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
19  20  21  22  23  6
25  26  27  28  29  12  
31  32  33  34  35  19
```

When the operation is done, I need it to look something like this
df1:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   2   21  22  23  6
7   8   27  28  29  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18
```

The column F is the primary key

I tried the following but it's giving a very strange output

```
for i in df2['F']:
    for j in df1['F']:
        if i==j:
            df1['D'] = df2['D'].astype(str)            
            df1['E'] = df2['E'].astype(str)
            df1['C'] = df2['C'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge can be used for that:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='F')
```

Note that if both dataframes have the same column names, the new_df will contain new column names with '_x' and '_y' suffix.

After merging you can decide which columns to keep

To copy values only if they exist you could:

```
import numpy as np
new_df['A_x'] = np.where(new_df['A_y'].isnull(), new_df['A_x'], new_df['A_y'])
```

It will update the cell only if the new value is not null.

Explaining np.where:
np.where(, , )
Basically I am checking if the value in the "new column" just merged is null. If it is null then "update" the old column with the current value in the column. If it is not null, then update the old column with the new value from the merged column

Comment: Is there a way I can loop over the dataframes and only replace values if the key matches?

Comment: Looping through dataframes is easy, but please explain what you mean by "if matches". If the index exists you want to copy the value but if not then continue with the existing value?

Comment: Yes I want to exactly do that. If it doesn't match then go ahead with the old values

Comment: It worked! Can you tell me how it works tho? As in the explanation?

Comment: I have added an explanation. Please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
cols = ['C', 'D', 'E']

df3 = df1.set_index('F')[cols]
df3.update(df2.set_index('F')[cols])

df1[cols] = df3[cols].astype(df1[cols].dtypes).values
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   2  21  22  23   6
1   7   8  27  28  29  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18
```

Comment: Apologies for the unclarity but I've updated the example. the first 2 rows have primary keys that exist in table 2 so C,D,E values are replaced. But for row 3, the key doesn't exist so its' value stays the same

Comment: @SuicidalAli. Ok but it doesn't change the solution. I'd already tested this scenario, I just updated the output.

Comment: Got the below error. Any fix?
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: You created a primary key with duplicate ids? A primary key should be unique else it's not a primary key

Comment: I basically concatenated a few columns to make the primary key which I don't think should have any dupes

Answer (score 0):

Tailoring the merge to the columns you seem to want from each input dataframe:

```py
df1 = df1[['A','B','F']].merge(df2[['C','D','E','F']], on='F', how='inner')
```

this will merge on matching values of the F column, common to df1 and df2.

Comment: I liked this method but it's changing the sequence of the columns. Also it's not showing me the rows which don't have the key

Comment: To reorder you can use `df1 = df1[sorted(df1)]`. For the last point, you need to change the merge logic from `inner` (only taking the intersection of keys) to `outer` (taking the union). There is also `left` and `right` taking all the values in the lhs or rhs of the merge